# Creating stored procedure in derby database in netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: stored-procedures, derby

I am using netbeans 8.0.1 and derby database. While creating Stored Procedure I am getting following error :

> Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line
>   2, column 39.

Here is my Stored Procedure Code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertSignUp(IN uname VARCHAR(50), IN pwd VARCHAR(50), IN fname VARCHAR(20), IN mname VARCHAR(20), IN lname VARCHAR(20), IN dob DATE(10), IN clg VARCHAR(20), IN workInfo VARCHAR(20), IN contact VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN
DECLARE @LAST_INSERT_ID INT
DECLARE @EXECUTION_OK char(1)
SET @EXECUTION_OK = 1

insert into Users(User_ID, User_Name, User_Password) values ( , uname, pwd)
SELECT @LAST_INSERT_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()

insert into Profile_Info(PROINFO_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, DOB, COLLAGE_NAME, WORK_INFO, CONTACT_NO, USER_ID)
 values ( , fname, mname, lname, dob, clg, workInfo, contact, @LAST_INSERT_ID)
GO

If exists( Select USER_ID from Profile_Info where USER_ID= @LAST_INSERT_ID)
Begin
@EXECUTION_OK = 0
End
END $$
```

Comment: Your subject says "Derby database", yet you have tagged the question with `mysql` and the syntax is clearly for MySQL as well. What are you really using?

Comment: Yes I am using "Derby database"
So can you tel me how to write above stored procedure in Derby.

Comment: "SQL state 42X01:" is kind of syntax error in derby database.
so can you please show me whats the correct syntax for above stored procedure.

Comment: Derby does not have stored procedures. You can only write them in Java. Details are in the manual: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefcreateprocedurestatement.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply on this.
but I am still confused to how to write this in java.
can you please elaborate this with example.

Comment: There is extensive information about this Derby functionality in the Derby Developer Guide: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevspecial.html